# Formatting multiple columns of data in a text file

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am learning python as of right now so I am still new. I have made an encryption system that outputs the initial password, encrypted password, and date to a text file. The method right now is very simple:

```
now = datetime.now()
date = ('%s/%s/%s %s:%s:%s' % (now.day, now.month, now.year, now.hour, now.minute, now.second))
writePass = finalPass.translate(passSwap)
with open("capec_dictionary.txt", "a") as text_file:
    print(initialPass.format(), "      -      ", writePass.format(), "      -      ", date, file=text_file)
    print("Password has been saved to dictionary.")
```

The result is as shown:

```
hi       -       *******       -       18/9/2015 17:55:15
hello       -       **********       -       18/9/2015 17:55:20
test       -       **********       -       18/9/2015 17:55:23
testing       -       **********       -       18/9/2015 17:55:28
password       -       *************       -       18/9/2015 17:55:34
passwords       -       **************       -       18/9/2015 17:55:45
myspecialpassword       -       ************************       -       18/9/2015 17:55:57
myspecialpass       -       *******************       -       18/9/2015 17:56:2
imlearningpython       -       *******************       -       18/9/2015 17:56:15
imlearning       -       ***************       -       18/9/2015 17:56:21
sillypass      -       **************       -       18/9/2015 17:56:29
lamepass       -       *************       -       18/9/2015 17:56:38
testcomplete       -       ******************       -       18/9/2015 17:56:56
test       -       *********       -       18/9/2015 17:57:0
testing       -       ************       -       18/9/2015 17:57:6
goodbye       -       ************       -       18/9/2015 17:57:9
bye       -       ********       -       18/9/2015 17:57:17
```

This is really messy and I want to clean in up.
First.. can I append something in python to make a header of "Pass" "Encryption" and "date"? Secondly I want to generate code in which it can be better formatted. For example, the longest string to to be five spaces between.

Something like this:

```
Password                  Encryption                       Date

hi                        *******                          18/9/2015 17:55:15
hello                     **********                       18/9/2015 17:55:20
test                      **********                       18/9/2015 17:55:23
testing                   **********                       18/9/2015 17:55:28
password                  *************                    18/9/2015 17:55:34
passwords                 **************                   18/9/2015 17:55:45
myspecialpassword         ************************         18/9/2015 17:55:57
myspecialpass             *******************              18/9/2015 17:56:2
imlearningpython          *******************              18/9/2015 17:56:15
imlearning                ***************                  18/9/2015 17:56:21
sillypass                 **************                   18/9/2015 17:56:29
lamepass                  *************                    18/9/2015 17:56:38
testcomplete              ******************               18/9/2015 17:56:56
test                      *********                        18/9/2015 17:57:0
testing                   ************                     18/9/2015 17:57:6
goodbye                   ************                     18/9/2015 17:57:9
bye                       ********                         18/9/2015 17:57:17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the .format() method of the string object. E.g.

```
date = datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')

with open("capec_dictionary.txt", "a") as text_file:
    template = '{:24s} {:24s} {:18s}\n'
    text_file.write(template.format('Pass', 'Encryption', 'Date'))

    writePass = finalPass.translate(passSwap)
    text_file.write(template.format(finalPass, writePass, date))
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there anything I can do about the header (Password, Encrypt, Date)?

Comment: I added that also.. See the ```print(template.format('Pass', 'Encryption', 'Date'))``` line

Comment: I'm sorry I did not see this. Unfortunatly using this method gives me an error "invalid format string"

Comment: else:
            date = datetime.now().strftime('%D %T')

        with open("capec_dictionary.txt", "a") as text_file:
            template = '{:24s} {:24s} {:18s}'
            print(template.format('Pass', 'Encryption', 'Date'))

            writePass = finalPass.translate(passSwap)
            print(template.format(finalPass, writePass, date))
            print("Password has been saved to dictionary.")

Comment: Sorry.. didn't know it would look that messed up on here. Yes I believe I typed it correctly.

Comment: date = datetime.now().strftime('%D %T')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90080/discussion-between-chad-simmons-and-gavin-youker).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something like

```
print('{:8s}'.format(my_str))
```

This will pad your string on the right with spaces to ensure it's 8 characters wide.

As for the header, you can just put that in the file as a fixed string.